# Autocomplete text box in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've am new to Google App Script. I have a spreadsheet that has various fields. I need to create a text box that displays the results from a particular field as I type the characters in the text box. I can do this like type the text and then hit a button and then display the results or the rowindex. But what I need is to an instant result showing up in a drop down box. Thanks. Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application to use HtmlService with jQuery-UI. Take a look at [Populate jQuery autocomplete list using value array from Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216) for an example that does just what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

See also this library that uses UiApp only

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/suggest-box