# Populate jQuery autocomplete list using value array from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the following [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DPlugins%2Fautocomplete%26redirect%3Dno) autocomplete feature in an HTML service textbox.

I am successfully able to do so, but I want to change the available tags. The tags should be from a spreadsheet. I have tried the following..any help please.

```
<script>
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktm2RhQU1uRUgtaXc");
   var s = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
   var lastrow = s.getLastRow();
   var list = s.getRange(2,3, lastrow).getValues();
   for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)  {

  }

    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [list[i][0]];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
    });
</script>
```

Any help how can I modify the code to link the availableTags properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Good Idea to separate the UI HTML from the Apps Script code that will populate your list. So first, here's how to separate those bits, with the `availableTags` list getting returned from an Apps Script function. (Adapted from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796695/1677912) to a similar question.)

Published as a web app, this will yield an input box with the autocomplete function attached, where the available tags have been provided from an apps script function. We call that function when the page loads, like this:

```
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
                       .getAvailableTags();
```

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('Autocomplete');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality');

  return htmlOutput;
}

function getAvailableTags() {
  // In production code, get an array of options by
  // reading a spreadsheet.
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

  return( availableTags );
}
```

#### Autocomplete.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
</script>
```

#### getAvailableTags()

With the framework working as above, you can move on to populating the `availableTags` list from your spreadsheet, replacing the fixed array we've started with. Something like this:

```
function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktm2RhQU1uRUgtaXc");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = 1; // number of header rows to skip at top
  var tagColumn = 2; // column # (0-based) containing tag

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
    availableTags.push(data[row][tagColumn]);
  }

  return( availableTags );
}
```

Comment: A mere improvement in the case that the range is greater than the number of rows in the column that is required. https://gist.github.com/wchiquito/6105659

Comment: @WilliamChiquito - that's a good improvement - as any kind of error checking would be. It definitely belongs in the final code solution. (I tend to leave that out of most SO answers, unless error handling is the crux of the issue.)

Comment: Ditto...on the spot...YOU R SIMPY GR8...no need to do any research..any work...simpley pasted your code and dhammmm....AS ALWAYS THANKS for your precious time....by the way I am going step by step on each to learn the logic..any suggestions on how can I learn this all thing....

Comment: Start with javascript - I recommend Codecademy. Work through some of [Google's Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles?csw=1). Use some of the [tag:google-apps-script] questions on SO as practice challenges. After that, different problems will introduce new learning opportunities... HTML & jQuery for HtmlService UIs, XML for parsing or serving data... you'll never be done!

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad, it worked perfect! I wouldn't be able to do this without your help.

Comment: is there a way to set these autocomplete options as the default options to an appended text box?