# Google form with a filter field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a google form with a field which takes the values as a list from spreadsheet. Right now i'm using formRanger scrip but my list is to long, 200 entries, how can i make it similar to android contact search. That it will filter the entries based on keystroke.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that nothing has changed in the last 8 years and the best solution to date seems to:

1. put the long list as a single question on separate section
2. advice users to use Ctrl+F to find the needed option.

This has advantage over drop-down that it's much easier to scroll the whole page than dropdown which user can accidentally close and will need to open and search again.

[image: Long list search on Google Form]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for an **"Autocomplete"** entry for your form.

As the user types an entry into the form field, a dropdown list appears showing matching entries lifted from a Google spreadsheet column.

The following solution using HtmlService works great for lists having over 200 entries.
I've tried it!

"[Populate jQuery autocomplete list using value array from Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216)"

Comment: thank you about response but how can i implement it on my form?? where to run the script? the code returns the array and how to autocomplete on google form? there is not such field!!

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this - did anyone find one?