# How to make Google Forms dropdown list searchable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

how do I create a Google Form with searchable dropdown list. For example, as seen in the picture link below, if I type "u", all the options with the letter "u" would appear. Thank you.

[example of what i would like to see in Google Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8NsE.jpg)

Comment: It is currently not possible to do it on Drop Down field of Google Form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google form with a filter field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119781/google-form-with-a-filter-field)