# Alternatives to suggestBox in a Google UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script, jquery-autocomplete, suggestbox

I'm trying to create a relatively simple app (or at least it seemed that way two weeks ago) to catalog periodical intake in a library.  I need a form with two boxes: text input for periodical titles and date input for publication date.  I then need this form to submit to a Google Spreadsheet.  I could just use a generic form, but I need it to autocomplete the periodical title as the information is being entered.
I'm using Google Apps, Spreadsheets, and Sites because they're free and do most of what I want.  Here's the sticking point.  I can create an HTMLService that autocompletes perfectly from a Google sheet.  [I basically followed this post exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216).
I can create a script that is a UiApp for submitting to a sheet.  I just can't do both with one project.  The code follows:

```
function doGet() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Periodical Intake');
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Title:'));

  // Text entered in the text box is passed in to pTitle
  // The setName method will make those widgets available by
  // the given name to the server handlers later
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('pTitle').setId('pTitle'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Date:'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setName('date').setId('date'));


  // Text entered in the text box is passed in to city.

  // Create a vertical panel..
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  // ...and add the grid to the panel
  panel.add(grid);

 // Here's where this script diverges from the previous script.
  // We create a horizontal panel called buttonPanel to hold two buttons, one for submitting the contents of the form
  // to the Spreadsheet, the other to close the form.

  var buttonPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();

  // Two buttons get added to buttonPanel: button (for submits) and closeButton (for closing the form)
  // For the submit button we create a server click handler submitHandler and pass submitHandler to the button as a click handler.
  // the function submit gets called when the submit button is clicked.
  var button = app.createButton('submit');
  var submitHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('submit');
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
  buttonPanel.add(button);

  // For the close button, we create a server click handler closeHandler and pass closeHandler to the close button as a click handler.
  // The function close is called when the close button is clicked.
  var closeButton = app.createButton('close');
  var closeHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('close');
  closeButton.addClickHandler(closeHandler);
  buttonPanel.add(closeButton);


  // Create label called statusLabel and make it invisible; add buttonPanel and statusLabel to the main display panel.
  var statusLabel = app.createLabel().setId('status').setVisible(false);
  panel.add(statusLabel);

  panel.add(buttonPanel);

  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

// Close everything return when the close button is clicked
function close() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  // The following line is REQUIRED for the widget to actually close.
  return app;
}

// function called when submit button is clicked
function submit(e) {

  // Write the data in the text boxes back to the Spreadsheet
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();

  var cell = doc.getRange('a1').offset(lastRow, 0);
  cell.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.pTitle);
  cell.offset(1, 2).setValue(e.parameter.date);


  // Clear the values from the text boxes so that new values can be entered
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('pTitle').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('date').setValue('');
  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  app.getElementById('status').setVisible(true).setText('The periodical ' + e.parameter.pTitle + ' was entered.' +
  'To add another, type in the information and click submit. To exit, click close.');
  return app;
}​
```

I could use my getAvailableTags function if it's possible to use jQuery in a UiApp (I don't think it is).  The other suggestion is to use [suggestBox](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/suggest-box) but it seems that has been deprecated.  I'm at my wit's end.  It's been two weeks and I feel I haven't gotten anywhere.  Can anyone please help a librarian out?

Comment: since we can't mix UiApp and HTMLService why not build your form in HTMLService as well, integrating the autocomplete in the form itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a form built with HTMLService that keeps data in a spreadsheet. I has also a file upload that you don't need but I thought it could interest someone else...
The autocomplete feature should be easy to integrate using you existing [code borrowed from Mogsdad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216)

code.gs:

```
    function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
    }    

   function serverFunc(theForm) {
      var fileBlob = theForm.theFile;         // This is a Blob.
      var name = theForm.name;
      var number = theForm.number;
      var adoc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);   
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dx0mr4Dy64jqmliTjFyHF7rZW4TZ_PPkWyA_H3WTRcA').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4).setValues([[adoc.getName(),adoc.getUrl(),name,number]]);
       return adoc.getUrl();
    }
```

index.html :

```
<style>
p {
margin:40px;
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
font-size:10pt;
color:#AAA
}
</style>
<p>
Test this file upload form :
<br><br>
<form>
   Enter you name    <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
   Enter your number <input type="text" name="number"><br>
   select your file  <input type="file" name="theFile"><br>
   <input type="button"  value="UpLoad" id="button" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cliHandler).serverFunc(this.parentNode)">
</form>
</div><br>
<div id="url" >
</div><br>
<div id="urlText" >
</p>

<script>

function cliHandler(e){
   document.getElementById('button').value = "Your file has been uploaded" ; 
   var divUrl = document.getElementById('url');
   divUrl.innerHTML = '<a href="' + e + '">Open the file</a>';
   document.getElementById('urlText').innerHTML = "url : "+e;
   }

</script>
```

---

EDIT : Here is a version based on your code with a working form and autocomplete:

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Autocomplete').evaluate().setTitle('Periodical Intake');
}


function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Agz7u97dbdECdGh6QVcyb2NVeFByTnlYeU5KcDdSRWc");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Cataloging Key");
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = 0; // number of header rows to skip at top
  var tagColumn = 0; // column # (0-based) containing tag

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
    availableTags.push(data[row][tagColumn]);
  }

  return( availableTags );
}


function doPost(e) {
  var title = e.title;
  var date = e.date;
  Logger.log(title+'  '+date);
}
```

Autocomplete.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
p {
margin:40px;
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
font-size:10pt;
color:#AAA
}
</style>
<p>
Test this file upload form :
<br><br>
<div>
<form class="ui-widget" >
      <input id="title" type=text placeholder="Periodical Title:" name="title" /><br />
      <input id="date"  type=date placeholder="Publication Date: " name="date" /><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run.doPost(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

</div><br>
<div id="url" >
</div><br>
<div id="urlText" >
</p>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.

$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList).getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#title" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm sorry but I integrated that into my Autocomplete function from Mogsdad.  The Autocomplete still works but the form doesn't submit.  Do I need to alter any of the serverFunc to specify a form name? [Link to the code](https://script.google.com/d/18Qi5KHW_g1z5x_miIQzemd_N3P9YVKGLupOv-BoJRF7RCbpd-4LXvgef/edit?usp=sharing) @Serge

Comment: Thanks again.  That gets me further, but how do I identify the Google spreadsheet where I want the form data sent to?  I also want the form to reset upon submission. @Serge

Comment: use a part of the function serverFunc(theForm) from the first version in the doPost function in code.gs. to reselt the form you'll have to do it in the client javascript. No time now but I'll try to update with these features later again ;)

Comment: Once again, thanks so much.  I really appreciate it, although I need a bit more help.  I've been playing around with it but can't get the serverFunc properly integrated into doPost to allow posting.  @Serge