# Integrate autocomplete list value array from Google Spreadsheet in a webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add an autofill to a textbox in a google-sheet webapp which refers to data from a specific column of the sheet.
The same is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216), but the code published there didn't work for me. I tried the same, but unfortunately it didn't work.

The debugger shows no bugs. The textbox is loaded, but the tags aren't loaded. Insteat I just see one available tag suggestion which is called "hybrid". I have no clue where this value comes from (I have nothing like that in my spreadsheet).

*Picture:*
This is the result - where does hybrid come from? No idea.

[image]

I also tried the first method with the fixed values (Python etc.) - didn't work here too.

My **Code.gs:**

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('Autocomplete');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality');

  return htmlOutput;
}

function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1K-C2ihU88tDLg8iTq1Zz75MI89I-RuOutUEJilPUiw8");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = 1; // number of header rows to skip at top
  var tagColumn = 2; // column # (0-based) containing tag

  var availableTags = [], availableTag;
  for (var row = headers, len = data.length; row < len; row++) {
    availableTag = data[row][tagColumn];
    if (availableTag) availableTags.push(availableTag);
}

  return( availableTags );
}
```

My **Autocomplete.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
</script>
```

**-> The second version with fixed values - same result ( hybrid oO ) :**

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('Autocomplete');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality');

  return htmlOutput;
}

function getAvailableTags() {
  // In production code, get an array of options by
  // reading a spreadsheet.
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

  return( availableTags );
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Since you're running this on a browser, can you try clearing your browser cache and see if the problem still persists?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help :/

Comment: link to spreadsheet ?

Comment: I changed the CSS and JS URLs to use `https://` and it worked fine.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It was the missing "s" !